# how to send watchPosition() data to node.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

After I received coordinates of a user by using html5 , I want to send it to server side of the webpage and display it on the google map. I think that, I need to use node.js to listen and emit it, also Jquery for sending coordinates to server side; however, I receive coordinates but I don't know how to relate them with Jquery to let other users locate him/her. is there any tutorial or example that I can check and learn.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

If i get this right, you need to send data to the server and wait for a response, then using the response show something on google maps?

First, you can archieve this with all the backend solutions, not only with nodejs (i recomend using nodejs but is personal).

The only thing you need is a ajax request, so, without the need to reload the webpage you can send data to the server -> get the response -> use the response.

If you want persistence you can use websockets ([socket.io](http://www.socket.io))

In that case NodeJS is better (using websockets).

Here are some examples of ajax request:

[jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

[Pure Javascript](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp)